# Mobile Splash Page

Tags: javascript

I have a mobile site already, and what I want to do is add an image that shows up when you hit the page for 5 seconds. Once 5 seconds has passed it just disappears and you're at the homepage.

Is this possible for an android device? Is there a way to make the image display on the entire screen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier with jQuery. You can style a `div` to be your splash page and set a function to run when the page is loaded. After the 5 second duration, you can hide the `div`.

It could possibly look something like this:

```
$('div.introDiv').animate( {
    opacity: 'toggle' // if div is hidden, it will fade in
},
{
    duration: 5000, // in ms
    complete: function () {
        $('div.introDiv').animate(
            {
                opacity: 'toggle' // div will fade out
            },
            {
                duration: 5000, // 5 seconds
                complete:function () {                        
                    // hide div and show main content
                }
            })
    }
}
```

);

This isn't the only way to do this, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like...

```
<body onload="redirectMobile()">

var redirectMobile = function() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    window.location = 'http://www.google.com/';
  },5000);
};
```

or skip the function and do...

```
<body onload="setTimeout(function(){window.location = 'http://www.google.com/'},5000)">
```

Like the previous answer said, jquery or another way might be easier, but this should work with pure javascript.